# Android how can I get coordinates and add it to link automatically

Tags: java, android, string-concatenation

I'm developing an application that organized my addresses, and I would like to achieve the following:

When I click on the add address button there will be two text boxes, `Name` and `Link`. I want the `Link` text box to get the current location automatically and add the coordinates to this URL:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?q=
```

For example this is the coordinates `27.123456,49.123456` so the final result will be like this:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?q=27.123456,49.123456
```

I searched for hours but all I manged to do is to get the current location coordinates. So please guys if any one can help me with it I'll be extremely thankful.

*** Update this is the problem now :

```
public void buildLink(float textLatt, float textLot) {
return String.format("http://maps.google.com/maps?q=%f,%f", textLatt, textLot);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
txtmylink.setText(
    String.valueOf("http://maps.google.com/maps?q=") + 
    String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()) +
    String.valueOf(",") + 
    String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the coordinates it should be a simple string concatenation and set value on the edit text. You can do something like (pseudo code)

```
EditText et = findView(R.id.mylink)
et.setText(buildLink(lat, long))
```

-

```
void buildLink(float lat, float long){
    return String.format("http://maps.google.com/maps?q=%f,%f", lat,long)
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help, I was trying but I couldn't get it to work, so right now I'm stuck in this code :   
    public void buildLink(float textLatt, float textLot) {
    return String.format("http://maps.google.com/maps?q=%f,%f", textLatt, textLot);

Comment: I've updated the main question would you please check it out?